# Extracting dynamic values from JSON using Freemarker

Tags: json, freemarker

I want to extract value dynamically using freemarker from JSON.
Let say this is my input :

```
{"ABC" : {
   "DEF" : "someValue",
   "GHF" : "someValue2"
   }
}
```

This results in a value `${ABC.DEF} => someValue`

The problem I am in is`DEF or GHF` comes dynamically.

> **Example** :- If input it `DEF` I want to extract `${ABC.DEF}` and  if input is `GHF` I want to extract `${ABC.GHFF}`

May anyone advise me that how using `freemarker` and getting dynamic input I can extract the value.

Comment: What's the meaning of "DEF or GHF comes dynamically"? One time you have {"ABC": {"DEF": "sv"}}, and next time you get {"ABC": {"GHF": "sv2"}}?

Comment: This is constant {"ABC" : { "DEF" : "someValue", "GHF" : "someValue2" } }

Now I get DEF or GHF dynamically and depending upon input I have to extract ABC.<input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want `${ABC[key]}`, where `key` is a variable whose value is either `"DEF"` or `"GHF"`.